# How would I toggle through images upon clicking on the images past the last image in the object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, debugging

I'd like to toggle through the images inside of `imagesPath` object.  As of now, you can successfully toggle `plus` and `minus`.

In other words, upon clicking on the `plus` image, the `minus` gets toggled and vice versa.

Inside `updateObject()` method, I've added a key/value pair which adds the key `divide` with value `https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/43/43097.png`.

How would I be able to reach the `divide` image upon clicking (`plus` > `minus` > `divide`) and subsequently, be able to reach other key/values upon clicking past `divide`?

I have a feeling I have to tweak with `this.setState(state => ({open: !state.open}));` inside `toggleImage()` method but unsure how.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const imagesPath = {
    minus: "https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/131484/isolated/preview/a432fa4062ed3d68771db7c1d65ee885-minus-inside-circle-icon-by-vexels.png",
    plus: "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/glypho-generic-icons/64/plus-big-512.png"
};

console.log(imagesPath);

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            open: true
        };

        this.updateObject = this.updateObject.bind(this);
    }

    toggleImage = () => {
        this.setState(state => ({open: !state.open}));
    };

    updateObject = () => {
        for (let key in imagesPath) {
            key = "helloThere";
            imagesPath[key] = "some new url";
        }

        imagesPath["divide"] = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/43/43097.png";
    };

    getImageName = () => this.state.open ? 'plus' :  'minus';

    render() {
        const imageName = this.getImageName();

        return (
            <div className="App">
                <img src={imagesPath[imageName]} onClick={this.toggleImage} style={{maxWidth: '50px'}}/>
                {this.updateObject()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should store the images path in `state` of the component and avoid modifying data in the render (I moved it to `componentDidMount` in my examples). If I understood properly your description you want to achieve something like carousel so I prepared two examples. One on an array and the second on an object.

https://codesandbox.io/s/w0pvoqv7m5 - object

https://codesandbox.io/s/ojprx25q9y - array